# How do I remove or replace a built in alias in powershell?

Tags: powershell, alias

Powershell includes a built-in alias `diff` for the `Compare-Object` cmdlet. This is really annoying for me, as I'm used to using the Unix `diff` command.

Is there a way to remove the built in `diff` alias, or otherwise override it?

I've tried:

- `del alias:diff` - gives an error "Alias was not removed because alias diff is constant or read-only"
- `set-alias diff diff.exe` - gives an error similar to the above
- `function diff { diff.exe $args }` - the alias takes precedence

How do I get access to the "real" diff (without having to remember a different name)?

In case it matters, this is Powershell 3. I haven't tried it in version 4 yet, although version 4 also has a `wget` alias, but unlike diff I could remove that one...

Answer (score 55, accepted):

Try removing if forcefully.

```
del alias:diff -Force
```

Comment: Thank you!!! I really wish this was more obviously known from the MS powershell docs! Or at least suggested by Powershell.

Comment: **Note:** Be sure to check if the command is actually an _alias_. In newer versions of powershell, `Get-Command help` will show that `help` is actually a function, despite behaving like an alias to `Get-Help`. Functions can be handled with `Test-Path Function:\help`/`Remove-Item Function:\help`

Answer (score 2):

For Windows 10 1803 build 17134 it only removes a constant alias for the current window even if -Force is used.

Answer (score 1):

in certain cases, the `-option` is required

```
Set-Alias 'type' 'read-host' -force -option 'Constant','AllScope'
```

Win10 19xxx